# Order and truncate array of objects by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Say I have an array like this:

```
var array = [
  {
    title: "something", 
    date: //date object
  },
  {
    title: "another one", 
    date: //date object
  },
  {
    title: "something else", 
    date: //date object
  },
  {
    title: "title here", 
    date: //date object
  },
  {
    title: "final one", 
    date: //date object
  }
];
```

The array is in no particular order. I want to order by date, so the object with the most recent date value is at the start and the object with the oldest date is at the end of the array. Then I want to truncate the array so I'm left with 3 objects in it (being the 3 with the most recent date).

Is this possible in javascript?

Comment: [Arrays can be easily sorted.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: [and sliced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely it is:

```
array.sort(function(a, b){
    return b.date.getTime() - a.date.getTime();
}).slice(0, 3);
```

We utilize the [.getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method of Date type objects to sort in descending order.

It gives:

```
[ { title: 'something', date: Sat, 20 Dec 2014 00:00:00 GMT },
  { title: 'something else', date: Wed, 10 Dec 2014 00:00:00 GMT },
  { title: 'final one', date: Thu, 20 Nov 2014 00:00:00 GMT } ]
```

on input:

```
var array = [
  {
    title: "something", 
    date: new Date("2014-12-20")
  },
  {
    title: "another one", 
    date: new Date("2014-10-20")
  },
  {
    title: "something else", 
    date: new Date("2014-12-10")
  },
  {
    title: "title here", 
    date: new Date("2014-02-20")
  },
  {
    title: "final one", 
    date: new Date("2014-11-20")
  }
];
```

Comment: The dates of the input and output don't seem to match? Confusing

Comment: @Coop Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse (fall-back section) there is some strange behaviour with dates provided with `/`s

Comment: @Coop I updated the answer with compliant date format input. Hopefully, that will satisfy your need.